# column sum function not working properly after forach loop

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get sums of column "quantity" for 2 different product ids.

I have a nested "for each loop" to update multiple product id. after finishing the nested "foreach" I am trying to get the sums of the "quantity" column for the respective ids.

for example : there are 2 product ID 1 & 2. each time I submit the form, it will either create a new row/rows or else if already exists(transfer_id) then will update. After updating the row/rows, there is another foreach loop to get the sum of the "quantity" column for both product 1 and product 2. The problem is, I am getting same sum value for both product ID, while I should Get sum 88 for product 1 and 52 for product 2, I am getting 53 for both product

The table looks like :

[image]

My codes are :

```
foreach($request->transfer as $key => $value){
            
    $update_prdct_wrhs = Transfer::where('id',$request->transfer[$key] 
         ['transfer_id'])->update([
                'from'      => 0,
                'to'        => $request->transfer[$key]['storage_id'],
                'supply_id' => $id,
                'status'    => $request->transfer[$key]['status']
         ]);

    foreach($request->transfer[$key]['product'] as $n_key => $n_value){

          $product_ids[] = $request->transfer[$key]['product'][$n_key]['product_id'];
          $product_quantities[] = $request->transfer[$key]['product'][$n_key] 
          ['quantity'];
          $storage_ids[] = $request->transfer[$key]['storage_id'];

          $input['storage_id']   = $request->transfer[$key]['storage_id'];
          $input['product_id']   = $request->transfer[$key]['product'][$n_key] 
          ['product_id'];
          $input['transfer_id']  = $request->transfer[$key]['transfer_id'];
          $input['quantity']     = $request->transfer[$key]['product'][$n_key] 
          ['quantity'];

          $supply_to_storage[] =  StorageProduct::updateOrCreate(['transfer_id'=> 
          $request->transfer[$key]['transfer_id']],$input); 
    }
            
}

foreach($supply_to_storage as $d => $k){
     $a[] = $supply_to_storage[$d]->product_id;
}
        
$product_ids = array_unique($a);

foreach($product_ids as $fg => $dingdong){
    $sum_product_stock[] = StorageProduct::where('product_id',$product_ids[$fg])- 
    >sum('quantity');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping though the code to see values being produced?  I'd first add dumps to see the sum values after every iteration and make sure those values are being added to your array correctly.